# How does yield work here?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

The method `Thread.yield`:

> Causes the currently executing thread object to temporarily pause and
>   allow other threads to execute.

So in the following code:

```
public class Test implements Runnable {  

    private int stopValue;  

    public Fib(int stopValue){  
        this.stopValue = stopValue;  
    }  

    @Override  
    public void run() {  

        System.out.println("In test thread");  
        for(int i = 0; i < stopValue; i++){  
            c = i + 1;  
        }  

        System.out.println("Result = "+c);        
    }  

    public static void main(String[] args){  
        int defaultStop = 1024;  
        if(args.length > 0){   
            defaultStop = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);  
        }  
        Thread a = new Thread(new Fib(defaultStop));  
        System.out.println("In main");  
        a.setDaemon(true);  
        a.start();  
        Thread.yield();       
        System.out.println("Back in main");  
    }  

}
```

I expect that I should see:

1. `In main`  then
2. `In test thread`

and the rest would be undefined.   But I don't understand why sometimes I only see:
`In main` and `Back in main` and not any print statement from `Test` thread?

Comment: Extract from the [Java 7 javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#yield%28%29): *"A hint to the scheduler that the current thread is willing to yield its current use of a processor. The scheduler is free to ignore this hint. [...] It is rarely appropriate to use this method."*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

yield() is a hint to the OS scheduled but doesn't provide any guarantees in terms of scheduling.  It doesn't always pause very long. If you call it repeatly it might only take a few micro-seconds.

Starting a thread takes time and even if you main thread pauses briefly, it may finish before the background thread starts.

---

As you can see, yield() pauses very briefly.

```
long start = System.nanoTime();
long runs = 20000000;
for (int i = 0; i < runs; i++)
    Thread.yield();
long time = System.nanoTime() - start;
System.out.printf("Thread.yield() took an average of %,d ns.%n", time / runs);
```

prints

```
Thread.yield() took an average of 148 ns.
```

by comparison, System.nanoTime take longer on my machine.

```
long start = System.nanoTime();
long runs = 20000000;
for (int i = 0; i < runs; i++)
    System.nanoTime();
long time = System.nanoTime() - start;
System.out.printf("System.nanoTime() took an average of %,d ns.%n", time / runs);
```

prints

```
System.nanoTime() took an average of 656 ns.
```

Both times will vary from OS to OS and machine to machine.

Comment: So what you are saying is that this is caused by `daemon(true)`?

Comment: The fact the thread is a daemon makes no difference to scheduling, it only makes a difference to when the application stops.

Comment: But isn't `Test` thread of the same priority as `main` thread? So doesn't `yield` allow `Test` thread to run for a period of time?

Comment: They are the same priority. Even changing the priority is also a hint which is often ignored. The Test thread won't run until it has started and that takes time. yield() allows other threads to run, but they could run without it. yield() *increases* the chance of other threads running by giving a hint to the OS.

Comment: @Jim: yield only says to give way to some other thread, there could be many and not necessarily your Test thread. By the time you call yield, Test thread might not even be runnable, and never get executed, because it's a daemon.

Comment: On a similar topic, try timing how long `Thread.sleep(1)` takes with `System.nanoTime()` hint: not 1 ms. ;)

Comment: @PeterLawrey:But how do you know that it is only a hint? In the documentation it says: `Causes the currently executing thread object to temporarily pause and allow other threads to execute`.  
Is there other docs that clarifies this?

Comment: The clue is in "temporary pause" meaning for a short but unknown amount of time (could be 1 nano-second) and "allow" meaning "it could" to do something which can happen at any time anyway. I consider that a hint as I don't see any guarantees.

Comment: Isn't it the case that yeild may not pause at all? I understood it to be a hint as you say and its up to the OS to act on it, if at all? By "pause" we really mean give up a slice of CPU in favor of another thread right? Not sure how this behaves on non-preemptive time slicing scheduler OSs. I also assume theres the same overhead to "backing up" the registers and loading another thread's frames, just like natural thread switching? Feel free to correct me on my points if I've got that wrong!

Comment: @PeterLawrey Interestingly, the JLS 3 (17.9) states: *"Neither a sleep for a period of zero time nor a yield operation need have observable effects."* i.e. could be a no-op, but that sentence has disappeared in JLS 7 (17.3)... Not sure if that means anything as to whether yield being a no-op is still allowed or not.

Comment: And the javadoc does the opposite: Java 5 say "Causes the currently executing thread object to temporarily pause and allow other threads to execute." whereas Java 7 says: "A hint to the scheduler that the current thread is willing to yield its current use of a processor. The scheduler is free to ignore this hint." ... Whatever

Comment: Added some micro-benchmarks which show yield's pause can be very short.

Comment: @Toby - 'Not sure how this behaves on non-preemptive time slicing scheduler OSs' - are there any such things left, (I hope not:)?  The scheduler on a 'real' preemptive OS may do nothing on yield() because it has, say, three ready/running threads and eight cores - all ready threads can run, there is nothing waiting for a CPU to yield to, so it does nothing.  There would not be too much overhead in that case because no thread changes state, but it's still a kernel call :(

Comment: i see, thanks. so, does yield indeed pause (albeit briefly) even if it doesn't "yeild" (I mean give up processing to the scheduler for another thread)? It's all very interesting :)

Comment: @PeterLawrey - results seem just about what I would expect on a box with more cores than ready threads - just enough time for a ring cycle, status check then.. no change to thread states. Maybe if you max out your cores with several threads, yield() may do something?  Whether the 'something' is actually useful is another matter.

Comment: I get opposite results on my machine ;-) (nanotime @ 12ns quicker than yield @ 66ns)

Comment: @Toby - the 'pause' is just wasting cycles in most circumstances on modern boxes with multiple cores.

Comment: @assylias - 12ns?  Is your nanotime() actually connected to anything? <g>

Comment: @MartinJames I'm not sure what you mean, but if I replace it by a no-op I do get 0 ns, so it is doing something, but not much!

Comment: System.nanoTime() is 11 ns on my Ubuntu at home. It could be reading a corrected RDTSC which is what I do on boxes where the anoTime is particularly slow.

Answer (score 2):

Well, the yield() probably does nothing at all because the set of ready threads is less than the number of cores, in which case both threads can run anyway and main() will just continue to run on to the core it was running while the OS issues, (quite likely queues), a call to its intercore driver to run the new thread on another CPU core.  Then there's the interaction with 'System.out.println' - an output stream call that is probably protected with a mutex.

I cannot quickly find any understandable explanation of what yield() actually does in differing environments/CPU/OS - one of the reasons I have never used it.  The other is that I can't think of any use for it no matter how it works.

Comment: The one use I have seen is in testing when you want to increase the context switching artificially to try to trigger concurrency bugs that could otherwise go unobserved. That's BTW what the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#yield%28%29) points at: *"It is rarely appropriate to use this method. It may be useful for debugging or testing purposes, where it may help to reproduce bugs due to race conditions"*

Comment: @assylias - OK, yes, I rephrase 'no deliverable use' :)

Answer (score 0):

The main process might have exited before the thread got a chance to start. There is no guarantee that `Thread.yield()` will force the thread to run in any particular time. If the thread did not start, then the `setDaemon()` would have no effect.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing your Thread.yield() with:

```
try {
        Thread.sleep(500);
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex);
    }
```

Comment: Don't forget though that yield has very different semantics than sleep. If you want a real "pause", sleep is good but yield is about giving up CPU time to another thread if the OS's scheduler thinks that it'd be a good idea. It's a hint only.

Comment: You are definitely right. I was just giving him an example that will produce the output that he is looking for ;)

Answer (score 0):

@Peter's answer is a good one but I wanted to add some additional information as an answer.

First, as mentioned elsewhere, the `a.setDaemon(true)` causes the JVM to *not* wait for the `Thread a` to finish before quitting.  If your real question is how to make sure that the `Thread a` does it's work *before* the JVM shuts down then removing the `setDaemon(true)` may be the solution.  Daemon threads can be killed when the JVM exits.  Non-daemon threads  will be waited for.  So the `main()` method might return and the main thread might exit but your `Thread a` would still run to completion.

In terms of `Thread.yield()`, as you mention, the javadocs state:

> Causes the currently executing thread object to temporarily pause and allow other threads to execute.

This, however, is somewhat misleading.  For example, if you have 2 threads running and 2 or more processors on your architecture, then the `yield()` will effectively be a no-op.  There are no other threads in the run queue that are waiting for processor resources so the main thread would be quickly rescheduled and would continue running with minimal pause.

Even if your are running on a single CPU system and your `Main` does `yield()`, your `Thread a` goes to do a `System.out` which is IO.  The IO may block causing thread execution to switch back to `Main` immediately.

When it comes down to it, only in very unique circumstances is a use of `yield()` necessary.  I've done a *lot* of multithreading programming and I've never used it.  Trusting that the JVM thread scheduling will "do the right thing" in terms of time slicing is always recommended unless you have profiler output or expert advice to the contrary.